# Django keep variable in memory, even if i refresh the page

Tags: python, django, variables, static

I'm using Django Framework 1.7 with its webserver.

I have a custom class where I declare a static variable, a list, where I append some values:

```
class my_class:

    list = [] 

    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ): 
        [...]

    def append_value(self,value):
        self.list.append( value )
```

I use a static variable because I call this function different times.
During a single page load my class works well but I noticed that my_class.list never expire.

To reset the list I have to restart the webserver.

I come from PHP and Perl where every time you refresh a page all yor variables are cleared if you don't save them in some way.

I use session, sure, but I don't save that list into session, at least not voluntarily.

NOTE: I don't know, during script execution, the first or the last time I call my_class().

How can I reset the list every time I reload/change page?

EDIT:

**ok I try to explain better my situation**:

- I've got a class that is a "javascript repository". Its role is to respond with a string of javascript functions.
  Javascript functions are organized in indipendent modules (list of functions), so I can attach to my page just needed functions.
  Different modules can share same functions.
- In my view I specify the url of a function (it is in the same view), get_js_code, whose rule is to return javascript code (with: `return HttpResponse(code,content_type="application/x-javascript")` )
- get_js_code initiate that "javascript repository class", asking one or more modules (list of functions), and my class returns functions just one time, even if a function belongs to more than one module.
- in my template I specify get_js_code url as a javascript resource, and javascript code is downloaded with the page from Django

It works well *BUT*:

- a module is needed from every app, so I specify in a Middleware an url that brings to another app/function that initiate that class in order to attach as javascript resource the common javascript module.

**Here is the problem**:

- my "javascript repository class" has a list that contains returned javascript functions list in order to return a function just one time. It works well but just one time: infact if I reload the page the list does not expire and no javascript funtions are returned.

Very hard to explain, I hope its clear now.

PS: I was wrong, I don't initiate the class inside a Middleware.

PPS: I know that is unusual to put javascript code inside Python code, but I'm testing this solution.

Comment: Where is this class instantiated?

Comment: For example in a __Middleware__ and in a __View__

Answer (score 0):

Define it as an instance variable rather than a class variable.

```
class my_class:

    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ): 
        self.list = []
```

Note that if you're setting things in a middleware, you still need to be aware of this issue; never set any state in the `__init__` of a middleware class, because that is only executed once at process startup.

Comment: Thansk Daniel but: I can't set it as an istance variable because I call my function different time during the execution and: that class is not a middleware class, but it's instatiated in a middleware (too).

Comment: Well, it definitely seems like you're going about things the wrong way. What is the use case for this class? Why do you need it to be accessed from all these different places, and why can't you explicitly pass the data around?

Comment: Is initiate a class more than one time so strange? I'd like to find a solution and not a workaround

Comment: No, initializing a class and expecting it to retain values in certain cases but not in other cases, that's what's unusual.